# Export Report to PDF using Power BI Rest API

Tags: rest, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a Power BI Pro(Trial) account. I'm currently trying to export reports in the registered app (with all the required permissions) workspace through REST API Reports - Export To File In Group.

On giving the group ID and report ID in the API:
POST [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/reports/{reportId}/ExportTo](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/reports/%7BreportId%7D/ExportTo)

I'm getting the below error:
{
"error": {
"code": "InvalidRequest",
"message": "Report requested for export is not on dedicated capacity"
}
}
HTTP Status: 403

Can anyone help me with this issue? I want to make a use case where I am able to export the reports in PDF format? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Export to PDF via the API is only for Power BI Premium or Embedded, and workspaces assigned to those capacity types.

Comment: I have tried with a workspace on premium capacity, but then it gives a 404 error of Feature not found. Premium per user is not supported there @Jon

Answer (score 1):

You must have premium license for this.

Note that per user licenses do not work. This includes Pro licenses.

Comment: Even with pro trial license?